# Replace selected found text in Delphi 10 RAD Studio editor

Tags: delphi, ide

**Requirements:**

We have a text in Delphi RAD Studio editor and this text has been selected as a search result.

**What happens**

On any change (`Del` button or typing some text) changes are applied to the right of selection.

**Expected**

On any change (`Del` button or typing some text) the selected block is deleted and then the changes are applied.

**Question**

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour that you describe is simply how the IDE's search functionality is intended to work. You are expecting that when you search for text, the IDE will *select* occurrences of that text. However, it instead *highlights* occurrences.

There is no way (to the best of my knowledge) to alter this behaviour, short of writing an IDE plugin to implement your own search functionality.

Comment: Of course, one could use Search and Replace, but then each replacement is the same (or a function of the search string, when you use regular expressions).

Comment: FWIW, it should not be too hard to write a plugin. The search functionality is exposed in the OTAPI. When an occurrence of the search string is found, you only have to select the highlighted text and make it overwritable. Not too complicated.

Comment: In Delphi 10.1 Berlin a simple Ctrl-W should select the currently highlighted text. Didn't test with older versions.

Comment: GExperts Grep selects the found text, so it would show the behaviour you want.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this, use Ctrl + R.